# How to add style library event receivers?

Tags: event-handlers, event-receivers, style-library

how can I add an event receiver to the style library ? (can't find any templateid)

Comment: It has the same id as document library - 101

Comment: how to differentiate them for the event receiver ??

Comment: See this for more details. Since you only want to attach to Styles Library, you will have to attach using code - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/6ca86d4f-5c8c-4e48-8940-811799260e36

Answer (score 2):

On Elements.xml, use **ListUrl** instead of **ListTemplateId**

Answer (score 0):

A style library uses the document library template (101), so that is the ID you use to create an event receiver.

The following link provides a detailed list of template ID's for registration:
http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2008/01/sharepoint-registrationid-list-template.html